# I can't backup some orgmode files

Tags: org-mode, backup

I'm in a strange situation.

Emacs automatically backup all of my files except for some of my orgmode files.
And I can't understand why.

Do you have any idea how I can investigate and fix this?

Comment: What does `C-h v backup-inhibited` say when evaluated in the buffer of one of the files that don't get backed up? What does it say in other buffers?

Comment: Ghah! Me too! I found that something had set `backup-inhibited` to `t` (thanks @NickD) The only place I can see that being set is in `./elpa/org-plus-contrib-20181230/ox-odt.el`. Maybe that's the culprit?

Comment: ... and I can't seem to set it to nil in `Local Variables` - there must be something setting it to `t` as `org-mode` starts up. Maybe I can set it in a late-executing hook - I'll have time to investigate a bit later. On the other hand, maybe there's a good reason for it to be `t`???

Comment: Thanks @wef that's exactly it.  Why on earth does org-plus-contrib set `backup-inhibited` to `t`?  If you happen to find a fix let us know.

Comment: @Rene - not quite. I concluded that it was `vc-checkin` in my case (please refer to my answer below and see if it's your use-case).

Answer (score 2):

If your org files are under version control (which I would recommend) then `vc-checkin` sets `backup-inhibited` to `t`. This makes sense as my `.org` files are all under version control and don't need the `~` backup. (I use [Version Control Always](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VersionControlAlways) and [SRC - Simple Revision Control](http://www.catb.org/esr/src/)

If you really want the `~` backups as well, then `M-:` `(setq-local backup-inhibited nil)`.

Comment: Enable the `vc-make-backup-files` user option to get normal backups despite version-control.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I ran into similar problems was when some of my file or directory names matched a magic variable which is supposed to prevent saving of unwanted things. In my particular case, the project's directory was called something like `com.example.githook` and the `.git?` matched `completion-ignored-extensions`. It's been a while, though, so I'm not 100% it was that variable.

So, while I can't explain why your files are not backed up, maybe this gives you a hint at what to search for: do the filenames of the files which are not backed up look suspicious?

Comment: well not really.  My files names: `home1819.org` and `office1819.org`